# Why is res.cookie() not working in my sails.js app?

Tags: cookies, sails.js

Acording to sails.js docs, it is only needed to use req.cookie('name', 'value') in order to make it work, however I can't make it work.

error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 TypeError: res.cookie is not a function
    at Object.login [as acounts/login] (/home/emirc/Escritorio/projects/letrica-vB0.1/letrica-beta/api/controllers/AcountsController.js:154:9)

Comment: Do you have an example of the res.cookie() code in AccountsController.js?

Comment: I solve the issue ussing session store instead, in AccountsController.js I just had a res.cookie('key', key);